# INSERT not working in cx_oracle when used with execute. How to get it working?

Tags: python, cx-oracle, oracle11gr2

I am new to cx_oracle. I have established a connection and I am able to create and drop a table using execute.

Where I am failing is when I try to use "INSERT INTO ..." in execute. It doesn't show any error but it doesn't store any value either (I confirmed this by checking if the entry had taken place using sqlplus from shell). The code I used was:

```
table_name = "T1"
column = "D"
insert_value = "test value"

sqlcode = "INSERT INTO "+table_name+" ("+column+") VALUES ('"+insert_value+"')"
cursor.execute(sqlcode)
```

Please help me, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
J

Comment: More info http://stackoverflow.com/q/2847999.

Comment: You should accept the Venu's answer, which is correct.

Answer (score 12):

How can `cursor.commit` work when the methods in Cursor do not have commit, connections has this method and hence it should be:

```
    connection.commit()
```

Using `cursor.commit()` returns:
`AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'`

Answer (score 2):

Strange that you are not getting an error with that code; that's of course unless you are (sadly) calling the Cursor object, `connect`.

You need to have something like this somewhere, before all your code:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(usr, pwd, url)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Proceed then to replace `connect.execute(sqlcode)` with `cursor.execute(sqlcode)`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Actually I did use cursor rather than connect. I have just corrected my initial question to the right one.

Comment: I really appreciate you time. thanks. So even though I did use cursor.execute(). it still just doesnt work.

Comment: Did you use the `commit()` method as suggested?