# Python : Accessing oracle database and updating it

Tags: python, oracle

I am accessing oracle database and trying to update it using python. Below is my code :

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy
import math
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
def update_output_table(customer_id_list,column_name,column_vlaue_list) :
    num_rows_to_add = len(customer_id_list)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
    c = conn.cursor()

    for i in range(0,num_rows_to_add,1) :
        c.execute("""UPDATE output SET """+column_name+""" = %s WHERE customer_id = %s""" %(column_vlaue_list[i],customer_id_list[i]))

total_transaction_df = pd.read_sql("""select distinct b.customer_id,count(a.transaction_id) as total_transaction from transaction_fact a,customer_dim b where a.customer_id = b.CUSTOMER_ID group by b.CUSTOMER_ID""",conn)

# Update this details to the output table
update_output_table(list(total_transaction_df['CUSTOMER_ID']),'TOTAL_TRANSACTION',list(total_transaction_df['TOTAL_TRANSACTION']))

conn.close()
```

My program is getting executed completely but I don't see my database table getting updated. Can someone suggest where I am going wrong?

Note : I am a newbie.Sorry for asking silly doubts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847999/why-the-need-to-commit-explicitly-when-doing-an-update) you will find some info why you need it explicitely. Without commit your code is doing update then when closing connection all non-commited changes are rolled back so you see no changes in DB. 
You can also set `cx_Oracle.Connection.autocommit = 1` but this is not recommended way as you're loosing control over [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT037).