# Insert into mysql a python list

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I tried many times to solve my problem with other questions in stackoverflow with no success. I'm learning python right now.

I know how to do it in PHP but I need to do it in python.

I have a table `dentistas` with 4 columns id, web, email, telefono.

And I import from another file with a list containing web urls.

I want to insert those websurls in the web column.

The code that im using right now doesn't shows me an error in the terminal, but doesn't insert anything to the table:

```
# coding=utf-8
import MySQLdb
from parser import lista

bd = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test123', 'leads') # Connecting to the database
cursor = bd.cursor()         # Creating the cursor 

for x in lista:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dentistas(web) VALUES(%s)", (x,))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `commit()` and save your current database state.

Try using `bd.commit()` after the loop.

Comment: Thanks, was the commit()  ;)

Comment: forgot the previous answer.... have you comitted after making the changes in your database?

Comment: 100% turnaround haha but you are right! See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847999/why-the-need-to-commit-explicitly-when-doing-an-update question why you have to commit cursor executions that change your database.

Comment: Yes, was the commit()