# Why does PyMySQL delete query execute but does not delete records without error?

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

**Issue:**

I'm trying to run a delete query using `pymysql` via my function `delEODTmp` but it’s not doing anything (i.e. deleting the records). It also does not throw back any errors, making it hard to understand why it is not working.

**Troubleshooting:**

1) The function retSQL works like a charm, retrieving whatever Select string I throw at it. This confirms that my user login settings are correct input to `pymysql.connect`. I am doing this from a client to a `Mysql 5.7 server` on the same network.

2) On the same client connecting to the same server with the same credentials I can:

- Run the `SQL DELETE FROM t_EOD_tmp;` successfully from `workbench`
- Run the `SQL DELETE FROM t_EOD_tmp;` successfully from `phpMyAdmin`

3) I tried running the py script locally on the server but the delete query still does not work. Same outcome as from client.

**Questions:**

Seems like destructive queries are being blocked when executed from PyMySQL. 
Do I need to enable something from Python, from MySQL?

There doesn't seem to be **extensive** documentation on PyMySQL, so maybe it would be better to develop via a different MySQL Python library. Is there a better way?

**Code:**

```
import pymysql
import pandas

    query1 = '''SELECT * FROM t_EOD limit 1000;'''

    def retSQL(query):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=myServer, port=myPort, user=myUsr, password=myPwd, db=myDB)
    df = pd.read_sql(query,conn)
    print(df.head(5)) 
    conn.close() # closeSQL connection

def delEODTmp():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=myServer, port=myPort, user=myUsr, password=myPwd, db=myDB)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    q1 = '''DELETE FROM t_EOD_tmp;'''
    cur.execute(q1) 
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

retSQL(query1)
delEODTmp()
```

Comment: Remember to `conn.commit()`, before you close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to commit the changes before closing the connection:

`conn.commit()`

Comment: Ok great - now good. Found this post on conn.commit which explains why its needed   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847999/why-the-need-to-commit-explicitly-when-doing-an-update)

Answer (score 5):

Post-execution of your query, I think you have to call a commit to apply the changes to the DB.

```
    @staticmethod
    def delete(query=None):
        """
        This methods deletes the record
        :param query:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            db.query(Users).\
                filter_by(**query).\
                delete()
            db.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            db.rollback()
            raise Exception(e.message)
```

Hope this helps !