# When does sqlite3 roll back transactions in python, and when doesn't it?

Tags: python, sqlite, transactions

I am creating a little workshop to teach how to use python and SQL and came across this oddity. I wanted to show how to use the `with` statement to create a transaction with sqlite:

```
import sqlite3

filename = 'data/transaction.db'

print("_________________________")
print("Create Table")
with sqlite3.connect(filename) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sqls = [
        'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test',
        'CREATE TABLE test (i integer)',
        'INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(99)',
        'SELECT * FROM test']
    for sql in sqls:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print(cursor.fetchall())

print("_________________________")
print("Create Error with 'with'")        
try:
    with sqlite3.connect(filename) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sqls = [
            'update test set i = 1',
            'SELECT * FROM test',
            'fnord',   # <-- trigger error
            'update test set i = 0',]
        for sql in sqls:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            print(cursor.fetchall())
except sqlite3.OperationalError as err:
    print(err)
    # near "fnord": syntax error

print("_________________________")
print("Show Table")       
with sqlite3.connect(filename) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test')
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
        # (99,)
```

This works exactly as expected. However to prove that without the `with` block the executions would be done halfway I tried the following:

```
print("_________________________")
print("Create Error without 'with'")        
conn = sqlite3.connect(filename) 
cursor.execute(  'SELECT * FROM test')
print(cursor.fetchall())    
cursor.execute(  'UPDATE test SET i = 1 WHERE i = 99')
print(cursor.fetchall())    
cursor.execute(  'SELECT * FROM test')
print(cursor.fetchall())    
cursor.execute(  'update test set i = 0')
print(cursor.fetchall())    
cursor.execute(  'SELECT * FROM test')
print(cursor.fetchall())    
conn.close()

print("_________________________")
print("Show Table")       
with sqlite3.connect(filename) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test')
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
        # (99,)`
```

The whole output is:

```
_________________________
Create Table
[]
[]
[]
[(99,)]
_________________________
Create Error with 'with'
[]
[(1,)]
near "fnord": syntax error
_________________________
Show Table
(99,)
_________________________
Create Error without 'with'
[(99,)]
[]
[(1,)]
[]
[(0,)]
_________________________
Show Table
(99,)                            # Why is this not (0,)???
```

I am very confused as to why the last Block shows a 99 again. Eventually the plan is to add a try,except block with an exception, such that the SQL code mimics the first block - however I am confused without this already :).

Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

From the [python sqlite3 API doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions):

> The underlying sqlite3 library operates in autocommit mode by default,
>   but the Python sqlite3 module by default does not.
>
> autocommit mode means that statements that modify the database take
>   effect immediately. A BEGIN or SAVEPOINT statement disables autocommit
>   mode, and a COMMIT, a ROLLBACK, or a RELEASE that ends the outermost
>   transaction, turns autocommit mode back on.
>
> The Python sqlite3 module by default issues a BEGIN statement
>   implicitly before a Data Modification Language (DML) statement (i.e.
>   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE).

Python will rollback transactions if the connection is closed without a commit (or an explicit ROLLBACK is issued). No transactions are committed in this program.

FYI a new connection is created in the "Create error without 'with'" block, but no new cursor is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The Python `with` statement works with context managers.  Whereas some context managers will release resources and possibly close an object, it seems that at least with the `sqlite3.connection` object, it merely commits or rolls back transactions but does not close the connection.  This can be confirmed for the [DB-API 2.0 interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> # Successful, con.commit() is called automatically afterwards
> ...
> # con.rollback() is called after the with block finishes with an exception, the
> # exception is still raised and must be caught
> ...
> # Connection object used as context manager only commits or rollbacks transactions,
> # so the connection object should be closed manually
> ```

For the non-`with` statement block, you are never committing the transactions.  When the connection is closed, all changes are automatically rolled back.

You need to call

```
conn.commit();
```

See [Why the need to commit explicitly when doing an UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847999/why-the-need-to-commit-explicitly-when-doing-an-update) for more details.

As a side note, the section of your code titled *"Create Error without 'with'"* does not actually cause an error/exception.